# Normal distribution confidence interval (accuracy in 68-95-99.7 rule)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have to solutions for same problem and i would like to know accuracy for these both methods. Specifically accuracy of 68-95-99.7 rule.

### Problem:

Our random variable $X$ follows normal distribution with parameters $\sigma=15$ and estimated value for is $\mu=m(x)=127$. Parameter $\mu$ is estimated from calculating arithmetic mean from data set which has 30 random picked values(the actual data set is much larger than 30 but is unknown how large). This approximately follows normal distribution:

$$ X \sim N(127,15^2)  $$

Now i want to define $95\%$ confidence level for paremeter $\mu$.

### Solution a:

This can be achieved using following formula:

$$ m(x)\pm Z \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} $$

Where $m(x)$ is arithmetic mean of data set, $Z$ is value of normalized normal distribution $n$ is size of data set. We can define $Z$ with our confidence level since 95% of area needs to be in center which leaves $5\%$ of area in tails. Each tail has $\frac{5\%}{2}=2.5\%$ of the total area. We can find Z by looking at values from [standard normal table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table) .

$$ \phi(Z)=0.025 $$
$$ Z=-1.96 $$

Alternative solution: using [R(programming language)](https://www.r-project.org/)

`qnorm(0.025)
-1.959964`

Now plugging in values gives us:

$$ m(x)\pm Z \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} $$
$$ 127\pm 1.96\frac{15}{\sqrt{30}}$$
$$ 127\pm \approx -5.367681064  $$

### Solution b:

We can use [68–95–99.7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) rule which follows from [Chebyshev's inequality.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) According to this rule $95\%$ lies in between $2\sigma$ from $\mu$. Again we can assume that $2.5\%$ of area is in tails.

We can Z value with equation:

$$ Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} $$

$$ Z=\frac{(127-30)-127}{15}$$

$$ Z=-2$$

Which can be expected from [68–95–99.7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) rule

$$ m(x)\pm Z \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} $$

Again plugging in values with different Z value:

$$ 127 \pm -2\frac{15}{\sqrt{30}} $$

$$ 127 \pm \approx -5.477225575  $$

---

To my understanding $P(\mu -2\sigma \le X \le \mu + 2\sigma)\approx 0.95$ is only estimation and is not accurate(or is accurate in some range). But again how accurate is solution a where value of $Z$ is from standard normal table. We can see a little more accurate estimates to these from this picture:

[image: -||-]

Essentially this question boils down to that what is accuracy of standard normal table and how can you determine accuracy in both cases ? We can compare two results and see that

$$ 1 - \frac{5.367681064}{5.477225575}\approx 0.02 = 2\% $$

There is about $2\%$ difference in between these results.

---

If you see any problem with the reasoning or if you can provide insight on how you can determine accuracy in this that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Tuki

Comment: The probability that a standard-normal-distributed random variable $X$ satisfies $|X|\le 2$, is $95.45$%, for $|X|\le 1.96$ the probability is very close to $95$%

Comment: The 68-95-99.7 rule does *not* come from the chebyshev inequality. It comes from the normal quantile function (and yes, as Peter says, the $95$ is more precisely about $95.45$.) The Chebyshev inequality is a more general rule that applies as a conservative bound to any distribution with a finite variance and thus produces much more conservative numbers. More like a 0-75-89 rule.